# Is or are in this context

Tags: grammatical-number

'The next thing i wanna talk about is/are the modifications to the...'
You say you want to talk about a thing and it's singular so it could be is, but it could be are because the actual thing you're talking about it plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is. Your verb should agree with the subject as stated. In this case, the subject is "thing", which you rightly note is singular.